# ELF Relocation Types on MSP430

Tags: microcontroller, elf, msp430, relocation

I have to take a relocatable ELF file and fix the addresses in a MSP430-F5529 with red hat compiler (not TI). However, I don't understand how the relocations have to be made as I don't get the notation used.

[Here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa534/slaa534.pdf#page=70&zoom=auto,0,701.3) are the types and their details.

Let's take this one for example.

- Name : R_MSP430X_ABS20_ADR_DST
- Signedness : Unsigned
- ContainerSize : 32
- Field : [0,4]+[16,16]

And the following generated ASM :

`0C60 0000 : MOVA R12, &0x00000`

If we search the `MOVA` opcode in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_MSP430#MSP430X_20-bit_extension) we see that the structure of the opcode is as it follows:

`Offset      : [7]  [6]  [5]  [4]   [3]   [2]   [1]   [0]`

`Hex Value  : [0] [dst] [6] [src] [src] [src] [src] [src]`

We now know that dst *C* stands for *R12* and that the last 20 bits are for the address to be replaced (last 4 bits plus another 16 bits - last 4 0s-).

I know need to understand how to interpret `[0,4]+[16,16]`. Looks like the `[0,4]` references to the last 4 bits on the first 2 bytes (006**0** 0000), but how does it work ? And how should I read the `[16,16]` ?

Here is the quote of the explanation on the PDF in case someone understands.

> The field is specified using the tuple [CS, O, FS], where CS is the
> container size, O is the starting offset from the LSB of the container to the LSB of the field,
> and FS is the size of the field. All values are in bits. The notation [x,y]+[z,w] indicates that
> relocation occupies discontiguous bit ranges, which should be concatenated to form the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "Offset" values are wrong.

"ContainerSize: 32" means that you have to view the instruction as a single, little-endian, 32-bit value.
As a 32-bit value, it would be written as `00000C60`.
The four bytes are, in order, `60`, `0C`, `00`, and `00`.
The bits are as follows:

```
31302928272625242322212019181716151413121110 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
 a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a 0 0 0 0 s s s s 0 1 1 0 a a a a
```

Comment: The answer looks awesome. I really think you just solved it, but there is something I am worried about. Wikipedia says it is *Built around a 16-bit CPU*. Does it matter when reading 32 bytes ? Does this still read it like that ?

Comment: The relocation just describes how the fields are layed out in memory. This has nothing to do with how the CPU reads and executes them.

Comment: I am checking it tomorrw at work and will come back. If that is it I will figure out how to mark your answer as accepted ! Danke !